# postgres - c <parameter> = <value> not working for postgres 11 in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm running a Postgres inside a docker. I want to change the default config of Postgres so I'm running :

```
docker container run -d postgres -c max_connections=200 -c shared_buffers = 1GB -c effective_cache_size=3GB -c maintenance_work_mem=256MB -c checkpoint_completion_target=0.7 -c wal_buffers=16MB
```

But when I'm connecting to Postgres running:

```
 docker exec -it container_name psql
```

And then the result of :

```
SHOW max_connections;
```

is

```
 max_connections
-----------------
 100
(1 row)
```

And it's not just `max_connections`. None of the parameters are changed. And I don't know what is the problem with what I'm doing?

**Update:** I already have a running docker container and I want it to apply these parameters to it without needing to restart it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put spaces around the equals sign when using the "-c" option.  So you need something like `postgres -c max_connections=200`

When I try it with the spaces, it refused to start at all.  So I don't know what you are connecting to in order to `SHOW max_connections;`.  Maybe you already had a server running before you tried to start with the invalid syntax?

Comment: You are right. I already have a running server. But using the command without space did not work.

Comment: And with both spaced and not-spaced commands I get something like `35d1c90ef07bb73f4ad30951951498f574e125ba872404015d26006f3d013284` as result which I don't know what it means

Comment: I suspect that that hash value is being delivered by docker, not by postgres.  You might need docker-specific help, rather than dba help, with that.  If you already have a server running, you won't be able to start another one in the same container on the same port.  What if you remove all the options and just try to start a default instance now?

Comment: You mean like `docker-compose up -d`? I get `WARNING: Found orphan containers (mahan_postgres) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.`

Answer (score 0):

When running Postgresql with Docker, there are many ways to change configuration when starting a container.

It is explained in the [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) official documentation at this paragraph : [Database Configuration](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#database-configuration).

In our case, there is an example :

```
$ docker run -d --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres -c shared_buffers=256MB -c max_connections=200
```

So let's try this with Postgres 14 :

```
$ docker run -d --name pg14 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres:14 -c shared_buffers=256MB -c max_connections=200
```

Check it with psql :

```
$ docker exec -it pg14 psql -U postgres
```

If we execute `SHOW max_connections;`, 200 is displayed, so it worked .

⚠️ Setting this parameter on the command line will indeed **override** the configuration in *postgresql.conf*.

We can check the configuration file used by the container with :

```
$ docker exec pg14 cat /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

It contains :

```
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

Even if the `max_connections` parameter has been successfully changed on the command line, in the logs we still see the default value (from the config file I guess) :

```
$ docker logs pg14  | grep max_connections
...
selecting default max_connections ... 100
...
```